# Laplace using c# Where did I go wrong?

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to implement the Laplacian Filter but my output is always wrong:

[image]

I debugged for 4hours...somebody can give me some hint? Thanks!!

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Lap1();
    }
    void Lap1()
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(img);
        for (int x = 1; x < image.Width - 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 1; y < image.Height - 1; y++)
            {
                Color color2, color4, color5, color6, color8;
                color2 = image.GetPixel(x, y - 1);
                color4 = image.GetPixel(x - 1, y);
                color5 = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                color6 = image.GetPixel(x + 1, y);
                color8 = image.GetPixel(x, y + 1);
                int r = color2.R + color4.R + color5.R * (-4) + color6.R + color8.R;
                int g = color2.G + color4.G + color5.G * (-4) + color6.G + color8.G;
                int b = color2.B + color4.B + color5.B * (-4) + color6.B + color8.B;




                int avg = (r + g + b) / 3;
                if (avg > 255) avg = 255;
                if (avg < 0) avg = 0;
                image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(avg, avg, avg));
            }
        }
        pictureBox2.Image = image;


    }
```

[This is how it's supposed to work.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plgGAvZAIHE)

Comment: You can debug for 40 hours and get nowhere. Have you tried doing some calculations by hand and comparing them with your code's output? Does "order of operations" tell you something? What exactly do you want to multiply by minus four?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "wrong" but I see that you're looking at neighboring pixels. However, you are modifying the same image you're reading from, this will impact what neighboring pixels will be for the next pixel. Try reading from `img` instead of `image`.

Comment: Filters should read pixels from original image.

Comment: GetPixel, SetPixel sucks. Don't do that. Read bitmap to byte array and modify them, then convert it back to image using bitmap data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @AccessDenied You should write this as an answer.

Comment: I think @LasseVågsætherKarlsen should write the answer.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you are reading from and updating the same bitmap. So you end up reading from pixels you have just updated.

If "image" is your output bitmap then all your calls to GetPixel() should use your input bitmap, "img" .

Comment: You might want to consider a library to get this done, image manipulation is hard to debug and difficult to make fast.  Interpolating from adjacent pixels is called a "blur transform".  Removing color is a "grayscale conversion".  The AForge library can easily do this for example, and do it better.

Comment: if so, I would consider emguCV, which is a managed wrapper of OpenCV.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen  Thanks for your reply，I find the bug !!

Comment: Thank you all !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented above, your issue is that you are updating the same image you are reading from.

The following is a Linqpad program showing how your function works when updating a copy of an image:

```
void Main()
{
    Bitmap image = LoadPicture("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti7Ij.png");

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.DarkOliveGreen), new Rectangle(11, 11, 33, 44));
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.DarkOliveGreen), new Rectangle(33, 33, 33, 22));
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.DarkOliveGreen), new Rectangle(33, 11, 22, 44));
    }

    image.Dump();
    Bitmap image2 = Lap1(image);
    image2.Dump();
}

Bitmap Lap1(Bitmap image)
{
    var image2 = new Bitmap(image);
    for (int x = 1; x < image.Width - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < image.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            Color color2, color4, color5, color6, color8;
            color2 = image.GetPixel(x, y - 1);
            color4 = image.GetPixel(x - 1, y);
            color5 = image.GetPixel(x, y);
            color6 = image.GetPixel(x + 1, y);
            color8 = image.GetPixel(x, y + 1);
            int r = color2.R + color4.R + color5.R * (-4) + color6.R + color8.R;
            int g = color2.G + color4.G + color5.G * (-4) + color6.G + color8.G;
            int b = color2.B + color4.B + color5.B * (-4) + color6.B + color8.B;
            int avg = (r + g + b) / 3;
            if (avg > 255) avg = 255;
            if (avg < 0) avg = 0;
            image2.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(avg, avg, avg));
        }
    }
    return image2;
}

private Bitmap LoadPicture(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest wreq;
    HttpWebResponse wresp;
    Stream mystream;
    Bitmap bmp;

    bmp = null;
    mystream = null;
    wresp = null;
    try
    {
        wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wreq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wreq.GetResponse();

        if ((mystream = wresp.GetResponseStream()) != null)
            bmp = new Bitmap(mystream);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (mystream != null)
            mystream.Close();

        if (wresp != null)
            wresp.Close();
    }
    return (bmp);
}
```

And the result,

Before filter:
[image: before]

After filter:
[image: after]

Comment: Thanks you,I find the bug that I should use img.GetPixel instead of image.GetPixel.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your sample with Fast image processing. Of course it is still far from ideal code. There should be load, process and save methods.
It took some time to figure out that stride sometimes does not equal width*bytesPerPixel.

Furthermore averaging r,g,b is not correct ToGray conversion since eye perceive colors differently.

As per your code you should GetPixel from img, while setting pixel to image.

It is also recommended to process images in normalized double values from 0 to 1, but it's out of the question scope.

It's also weird to get pixels to implement kernel filter. It's better to pass matrix and compute values based on matrix, but not to hardcode.

It's also bad to block UI thread. Use TaskFactory for example.

```
(byte r, byte g, byte b) GetPixel(byte[] image,int x, int y, int bytesPerPixel,int stride)
{
      if (bytesPerPixel < 3) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(bytesPerPixel));
      byte b = image[x * bytesPerPixel + y * stride + 0];
      byte g = image[x * bytesPerPixel + y * stride + 1];
      byte r = image[x * bytesPerPixel + y * stride + 2];
      return (r, g, b);
}

byte ToGray((byte r, byte g, byte b) pixel)
{
   return NearestByte((int)(pixel.r * 0.3 + pixel.g * 0.59 + pixel.b * 0.11));
}

byte NearestByte(int a)
{
   return (byte)(Math.Min(255, Math.Max(0, a)));
}

void SetPixel(byte[] image, byte intensity, int x, int y, int bytesPerPixel, int stride)
{
    if (bytesPerPixel < 3) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(bytesPerPixel));
    image[x * bytesPerPixel + y * stride + 0] = intensity;
    image[x * bytesPerPixel + y * stride + 1] = intensity;
    image[x * bytesPerPixel + y * stride + 2] = intensity;
}

Bitmap ApplyLaplacianFilter(Bitmap input)
{            
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(input);         
    // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
     img.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
     img.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    var stride = bmpData.Stride;
    int bytesPerPixel = bmpData.Stride / img.Width;
    int bytes = img.Width * img.Height * bytesPerPixel;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
    img.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    int resultBytesPerPixel = 3;
    Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);            
    var bitmapData = resultBitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, resultBitmap.PixelFormat);

    int resultStride = bitmapData.Stride;              
    int resultBytes = resultStride * img.Height;    
    byte[] result = new byte[resultBytes];

    for (int y = 1; y < img.Height - 1; y++)
    {
       for (int x = 1; x < img.Width - 1; x++)
       {

         var left = GetPixel(rgbValues, x - 1, y, bytesPerPixel, stride);
         var right = GetPixel(rgbValues, x + 1, y, bytesPerPixel, stride);
         var top = GetPixel(rgbValues, x, y - 1, bytesPerPixel, stride);
         var bottom = GetPixel(rgbValues, x, y + 1, bytesPerPixel, stride);
         var center = GetPixel(rgbValues, x, y, bytesPerPixel, stride);

         var resultIntensity = NearestByte(
             ToGray(left) + ToGray(top) + ToGray(center) * (-4) + ToGray(right) + ToGray(bottom));
         SetPixel(result, resultIntensity, x, y, resultBytesPerPixel, resultStride);
       }
    }


   IntPtr resultPtr = bitmapData.Scan0;
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(result, 0, resultPtr, resultBytes);
   resultBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);            
   return resultBitmap;
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   pictureBox2.Image = await new TaskFactory().StartNew((image) => ApplyLaplacianFilter((Bitmap)image), pictureBox1.Image);                       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all (just for practical reasons), use logical names. GetPixel() returns a pixel not a colour. And it might be insightful add a suffix that refers to relative position of the pixel you want to compare with (N, NW, W, SW, S, SE, E).

What you want to have is something like this:

```
var detlaRed = Math.Abs((pixel_E.R + pixel_W.R + pixel_N.R + pixel_S.R) - 4* pixel);
```

So I think you want to have the absolute value.

Comment: Regarding the *logical names*: If you check the method declaration (`public System.Drawing.Color GetPixel (int x, int y)`) you can see that it actually returns a color.  So the names are perfectly fine.